# Magnific Popup titleSrc: undefine

Tags: javascript, jquery

Image title undefine then shows custom title.[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.gimg').magnificPopup({
     type:'image',
     gallery:{
         enabled:true,
        },
    image: {
        markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
        '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
        '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
          '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
          '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>',
    titleSrc: function(item) {
        return item.el.attr('title') + '<small class="image_title">by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
    }
}    


     
   
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the title tag to the element which has a `.gimg` class.

Below is the working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gimg').magnificPopup({
        type:'image',
        gallery:{
            enabled:true,
        },
        image: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>',
            titleSrc: function(item) {
                return item.el.attr('title') + '<small class="image_title">by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" integrity="sha512-+EoPw+Fiwh6eSeRK7zwIKG2MA8i3rV/DGa3tdttQGgWyatG/SkncT53KHQaS5Jh9MNOT3dmFL0FjTY08And/Cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" integrity="sha512-IsNh5E3eYy3tr/JiX2Yx4vsCujtkhwl7SLqgnwLNgf04Hrt9BT9SXlLlZlWx+OK4ndzAoALhsMNcCmkggjZB1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
<a class="gimg" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Image 1">Open popup</a>
```